# How is it changing macro in my MWE?

Tags: tables, graphics, tabularx, rotating

MWE

```
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{{OZGUR}} & \includegraphics[scale=.25]{o.jpg}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

output

[image]

That I want, center of the table of the text OZGUR. How is it changing macro in my MWE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The text is centered `origin=c`, then the rotation origin is the center of the rotated box. But then the vertical position will depend on both the width and height. This is avoided by `origin=Bc`, then the origin is on the baseline and the rotated text is vertically centered around the base line. Then the same can be achieved for the image using `\raisebox{-.5\height}{...}`, where `\height` is the height of the box.

```
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% option "demo" because of the missing image
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
  \rotatebox[origin=Bc]{90}{{OZGUR}} & 
  \raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[scale=.25]{o.jpg}}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}  
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: it's good working.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`adjustbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox)'s `valign=c` option as part of your `\includegraphics` option. This changes the vertical anchor from the baseline to the vertical center:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
  \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{{OZGUR}} & \includegraphics[scale=.25,valign=c]{example-image}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

For this to work, you need to `export` the properties of `adjustbox` upon package load.

Comment: I don't know this package. It's good for me.

Comment: The vertical position of `\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}` depends on the height and depth of the material to be rotated. With `origin=cB` the rotation center is kept on the current base line. `valign=c` of package `adjustbox` uses `\vcenter` for the centering, that means the middle axis is the *math* axis,  This can be fixed by putting the left part inside `\adjustbox{valign=c}{\rotatebox...}`. Then both the text and the image have the same middle axis and are correctly aligned to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Without tabular, another  solution could be use `graphbox` package to center vertically the image with the `align=c` option (or  `valign=c` of the `adjustbox` package as showed in other answer, that does not matter, but beware of be confused) and enclose the rotated label in two `\vrule`. That allow an easy fine tuning of the format of the rules, the spaces and image size without becoming entangled with a tabular-like environment. The code below show a simple `\rodcap` macro that using that approach, shrink the image if the specified maximum height is so big that the image is wider that the column of text, or center the image and the rotated label when the total width is smaller that `\linewith`.

> [image: MWE]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % dummy text for the MWE
\parindent0pt\parfillskip0pt % retangular paragraphs for the MWE
\usepackage{graphicx,rotating,xcolor,graphbox,lipsum}

% Usage: 
%\rotcap{<label>}{<maximum height<}{<imagename>}

\def\rotcap#1#2#3{\begin{figure}[!htbp]
{\hfill\color{olive}\vrule width 3.5pt}
\color{olive!50!black}
\hskip.5em\rotatebox[origin=Bc]{90}{\sffamily #1}
\hskip.5em{\color{olive!50}\vrule width 2pt}\hskip.5em%
\includegraphics[height=#2,width=.8\linewidth,keepaspectratio,
align=c]{#3}\hfill\mbox{}\end{figure}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2] %dummy text

\rotcap{OZGUR}{.5cm}{example-image}  % example of microscopic image 
\rotcap{OZGUR}{.15\textheight}{example-image} % example of little image 
\rotcap{OZGUR}{400cm}{example-image} % example of absurd zoom 

\lipsum[4] %dummy text
\end{document}
```